How to get gnome desktop from tty
I was reinstalling kde and trying to get genome but I am stuck a tty
But it shows no display environment specified
And there is no gdm
And I couldn't find the command to download genome gdm
I would be best if you could give the command as I am new
Also I am not able to open any app
It says no display environment specified

On properly configured machine you can just call
startx

That will start up currently istalled desktop environement from terminal session.
If that is not working maybe your installation was interrupted, so you could try again:
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop

If it's too much or not working for you frankly the simplest solution would be to reinstall your ubuntu os. You can choose os image that already have desired  desktop environment:

Gnome
KDE
or see other flavors

